# Extract value from data frame column based on another column?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame

```
Name  score1  score2  Total
john   5       15      20
doe    10      20      30
```

I know we can get the score 1 using frame$score1 but can i query based on another column.

I want to get where `total > 25 and score2 > 15` and get `score1`

Result:

```
score1
  10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done by creating a logical vector using `&` and `>` operators, extract the 'score1' values based on this `vector`

```
with(df1, score1[Total > 25 & score2 > 15])
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also do this:

```
df$score1[df$Total > 25 & df$score2 > 15]
```